# Creating a view with a default menu item not default task

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I want to create a View (or modify an existing one) so that the menu item type is MENU_LINKS_TO_PARENT, so that when I have sub menu's displayed for a page, the page has a link in the sub menu. This is exactly the same has having a default task, I just want it as a default menu item.

Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 0):

uhm, change hook_menu if you are allowed ( or use hook_menu_alter otherwise) to set the 'type' of each of your links to suit your specific needs. 
more info [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)

Comment: Unless I am incorrect, I don't believe I was able to edit a Views menu items using hook_menu_alter. Will double check.

Comment: yip, I confirmed this. It is not possible to modify a views menu items using hook_menu_alter.